# Spanish (Castillian) equivalent of "funny."

Tags: modismos

What are the equivalent uses of "funny" in these English expressions:

Amusing

> Jose is a great comedian.  He's a real funny guy.

Odd, unexpected, or undesired.

> This drink tastes funny.
>
> My car is making a funny noise.

Coincidence

> It's funny you should say that.  I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/funny

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Amusing

> Jose es un gran comediante. Es un tipo muy **divertido**.

Odd, unexpected, or undesired (We don't use funny in those cases).

> Esta bebida sabe **raro**.

> Mi coche hace un ruido muy **raro**.

Coincidence

> Es **gracioso** que digas eso. Yo estaba pensando lo mismo.

Comment: La frase "Está bebida sabe raro" me suena como si no tuviera consistencia, ya que el sujeto es femenino y el predicado masculino. A mí me suena mejor "Está bebida sabe rara", ¿no?

Comment: Sí, es un poco complicado. Tengo mezclas de modismos por residencias en varios sitios con habla diferente. En principio la bebida sabe rara, el sabor es raro. Creo que es más habitual escuchar –la Coca Cola sabe raro– en lugar de –la Coca Cola sabe rara–. Puede que me equivoque. En caso de bebida con género masculino, es indudable –el vino sabe raro–.

Comment: @karloswitt. En realidad es una sutileza.
"Esta bebida sabe raro" es una frase y no una oracion, pues "sabe" no es un verbo. El sujeto es implicito. Compara con
"El sabor de esta bebida es raro", Aqui puedes ver que el sujeto es el sabor, y el verbo es "es". Por eso esta bebida sabe raro

Comment: Gracias, porque ahora entiendo mejor el sentido de esta expresión.

Comment: @Joafigue Veo la diferencia, pero no entiendo que "sabe" no sea un verbo.

Comment: [*Saber*](https://www.rae.es/dpd/saber) en el sentido de *tener sabor* es un verbo intransitivo que se conjuga exactamente igual que el verbo *saber* de tener conocimiento de algo.

Comment: For coincidence I would say that "curioso" is also a valid answer

Answer (score 5):

I almost agree completely with @Danielillo's answer but ...

I can't find that "coincidence" aspect of funny in an English dictionary (see [Oxford](https://www.lexico.com/definition/funny) or [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/funny) online dictionaries for reference)

I think that OP's last sentence

> It's funny you should say that. I was thinking the same thing.

belongs to "Odd, **unexpected**, or undesired" too

The situation may cause amusement but I think that the main point is that it's **[peculiar](https://www.lexico.com/definition/peculiar)**. You can translate peculiar to Spanish directly as **peculiar** (changing its pronunciation). As you can use peculiar synonyms' in that sentence like odd or strange, the same applies in Spanish with their respective translations raro and extraño.

Note: I was not trying to offer an accurate equivalence between peculiar and funny in that sentence but to point that there isn't a third meaning associated with funny.

As @terdon commented, a Spanish idiomatic way of showing amazement is "¡Qué fuerte!". If your sentence were

> Funny/Wow/Awesome! I was thinking the same thing!

then you could translate it to Spanish as

> ¡Qué fuerte! ¡Yo estaba pensando lo mismo!

Comment: Idiomatically, at least in my admittedly non-native speaker's experience, one would say _que fuerte que digas eso_ or _es gracioso que digas eso_, but not _es peculiar_. You could, it just sounds much stronger than the English _it's funny you should say that_.

Comment: @terdon I think that "gracioso" is not the correct translation in that context in Spanish. i agree with you that "que fuerte" is more idiomatic but to express amazement. Not sure if that's the intention in English in that case. "Que fuerte!" can be translated as "Wow!" or "Awesome!"

Comment: In English, there is funny, ha ha, and funny, odd. They are not the same. In fact, people will often say, that is funny, ha ha when there is ambiguity.

Comment: True, @rubioRic, _que fuerte_ might be too strong here. It's just the use of _peculiar_ that I would find, ehm, peculiar in that context in Spanish. Largely because I believe that 
 (again, I stress that I am not a native Spanish speaker, so I may very well be wrong here) _peculiar_ in English is a more common word than _peculiar_ in Spanish, and "funny you should say that" is a very common phrase.  That said, if forced to translate the phrase, I would probably just use _que raro que digas esto, estaba justo pensando..._ Would you use _peculiar_ instead of _raro_?

Comment: It may depend on my mood or the circunstances. You're right, I wouldn't use peculiar probably. What I was trying to point in the answer is that the example belongs to the second meaning